# How does C++ compiler know the size of a object with superclasses

Tags: c++, object, superclass

Exactly as the question states!

Let's say I have the following snippet

```
class A
{
    int x;
    int y;
}

class B : public A
{
    int z;
}

class C
{
    A a;

    public C(A a) : a(a){}
}
```

What would happen if I called C's constructor with a B class, would it copy it's A part data in the class? Or also keep it's B data somewhere?

Thanks in advance! It might be a stupid question but I never understood actually.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). No excuse.

Comment: Heheh I have Absolute C++ and C++ Essentials at my home.:P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass an instance of `B` to the `C` constructor that takes an `A` by value, the `B` instance will be sliced, and just the `A` part will remain. So :

> > would it copy it's A part data in the class?

this.

So, specifically, there is no way to turn the `C::a` member back into a `B` instance with the same value for `z` as the original `B` instance - that information has been lost during the (irreversible) slicing operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps me becoming a master in C++:P

Answer (score 3):

> What would happen if I called C's constructor with a B class, would it copy it's A part data in the class?

Yes. This is known as *slicing* - the argument is created using `A`'s copy constructor, which just copies the `A` subobject.

> Or also keep it's B data somewhere?

No.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still need to wait 8 minutes to accept an answer though:P